# Getting PHP Referral with "&" in URL String

Tags: php, html, browser

I am trying to get the referring URL with PHP using:

```
echo  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

This is working, however when I attach variables to the URL string with "&"s, the referer shows as 
blank. If the &'s are replaced with the html version "& a m p;", the referer works again.

I need a way for the referer to work with the "&" symbol.

The referrer is going to be captured from tracking URLs like this one:

http://www.example.com/link.php?var1=data&var2=data&var3=data

Any suggestions/solutions would be greatly appreciated!

**I realize that the referer may be spoofed, but still wish to access this information.

Comment: Where are these URLs? If they're in the source of an XHTML document, then the ampersands _should_ be encoded. e.g. `<a href="http://www.example.com?var1=data&amp;var2=data&amp;var3=data" ...` is the correct form. However, none of this should be affecting the Referer...

Comment: They're typically being called from a MYSQL DB on user sites which are entered in the DB's with the "&" sign instead of the &amp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the URL manually, your browser won't sent the referer with the next request.  If you change the URL with firebug, then click on it, it should populate properly.

On a sidenote, you shouldn't trust the referer because people can tell their browser to submit anything they want as the referer.

Comment: I'm aware of the security vulnerability but still would like to see where some of the urls are coming from. I wouldn't be able to change the URL with firebug since these tracking URLs are used by our users, and are placed outside of our control.

Comment: If you don't have control over the URLs how are you trying to add URL parameters?

Comment: @David I think what we're saying is that we think the ampersands may be a red herring. Are you seeing this problem with a particular browser? How are you testing, exactly? What's the exact behaviour? Can you show us an example page where one link works and sends the Referer through, and one doesn't?

Comment: The URLs are basically advertising links generated automatically for users.  They place these links on their site which redirect to online advertisements.  The tracking variables contain the user ID, campaign ID, and similar information which is recorded before it is redirected to the advertisement.  The referring URL, IP, and other information is also recorded before the redirect.

Comment: It's frustrating because it's working without the & symbol or with &amp's.  But the "&" symbol somehow is causing the referrer to be completely null.

Comment: How are you adding them to the URL?  Do you click on the link on their page, then change in the nav bar?  Or change on their site?

Comment: The URLs are pre-populated with data when the users receive them, so they will receive a link like: http://www.example.com/link.php?var1=data&var2=data&var3=data - this would have their userID and relevant info - so the URLs should be clicked just as they are as a link on a page.

Comment: Do you think there is a way to use parse url or str_replace here?

Comment: nice demo!  The problem I am having is that when the "&" symbol is used in the actual html instead of the "&amp;", it is returning a blank referrer.

Comment: For example: <a href="link.php?var=val&var2=val2">link here</a> - this link is using &'s in the html - if you try that link it should return a blank ref

Comment: I've added a second link on the demo page.  It still works fine in chrome.  What browser are you using?

Comment: @David No, really, the ampersands should have no effect on the Referer. @amccausl's second example works fine for me in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. Have you got any kind of odd plugins in your browser, or any proxy server in the way that might be changing things? Any security software that might be doing something odd? Tried from a different browser/computer?

Comment: Thank you all for your help!....I realized the problem was because I have an .htaccess redirect which is forcing SSL on all links.  The tracking links were non-https so they were getting redirected and losing the referer.  Thanks again.

Comment: @David Cool. Makes sense; the referer is discarded when moving from https to http as a security feature.